# give out all min values when they are doubled in r

Tags: r

I've got a dataframe like this in a sorted tabled format:

```
> sort(table(Daywork$hour))

 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 16 17 19  2 22  1 15 18 20  0 23 21 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  2  2  2  2  3  3  4
```

Now i want to add a function which gives out the minimum or the maximum like:

```
min.Work(Daywork$hour)
 3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 16 17 19  
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

What functions are able to apply for such a question

Comment: if `x` is your vector, then `x[which(x == min(x))]` should work

Comment: as @Marcinthebox already saind: `df <- table(c(3:19, rep(c(2, 1,2,20:23), each =2))) -1; df[df == min(df)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may subset your table.

```
set.seed(42)
x <- sample(1:10, 100, replace=T)

table(x)
# x
# 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
# 9 13  6 13 13  9  6 11  9 11 

table(x)[table(x) == min(table(x))]
# x
# 3 7 
# 6 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You may `sort` the `table` and subset the first value. Using @jay.sf's data.

```
temp <- sort(table(x))
temp[temp == temp[1]]

#x
#3 7 
#6 6
```

to get `max` value :

```
temp[temp == temp[length(temp)]]
x
# 2  4  5 
#13 13 13
```